# ASP.NET-MVC3 with EF4.1, Editing navigation properties doesn't alter data after SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to edit entity with navigation property in ASP.NET-MVC3 with EF4.1

My models:

```
[DataContract]
public class Event
{       
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Place
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my data context class:

```
public class myDB: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
```

my controller post edit method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Event @event, string placeID)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        @event.Place = _db.Places.Find(placeID);

        _eventoDB.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _eventoDB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(@event);
}
```

I can see that the place changed in the `@event` from null to the new place after `@event.Place = _db.Places.Find(placeID);` but after `SaveChanges` the place id stays the same as it was before the edit. 
any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: The `[DataContract]` is not related to EF. And you should check if there is a column Event.PlaceId in the generated Db.

Comment: There is a Event.PlaceId in the generated DB, there is also the id of the place I chose when I created the Event object but for some reason after editing, the placeid value doesn't changed

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may be happening because your Event object is not attached to the context. EF objects coming from an MVC request are not part of the context until you manually attach them.  This may fix it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Event @event, string placeID)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _eventoDB.Events.Attach(@event);
        @event.Place = _db.Places.Find(placeID);
        // should not need to mark as modified, previous line will do it
        // _eventoDB.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _eventoDB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(@event);
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, I checked the _db.Entry(@event).State before _db.Events.Attach(@event) and the state is Detached. The problem is after attach and setting of @event.place the state is Unchanged. I changed the state manually to modified and call SaveChanges than I got the following exception "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made..." any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After I tried SonicDynamite solution I got the following exception "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."

After some google research I found out that adding a property

```
public string PlaceId { get; set; }
```

to my Event entity solve the problem.

In addition there is no need to attach the event object like SonicDynamite suggested

I have no idea why it works with the PlaceId property, can any one explain it please?

Thanks!

Comment: What did the innerException say?

Comment: the innerException is "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

Comment: Stack Trace:    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()